# How can I configure OS X Mavericks to use a UK PC keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I'm using a non-mac USB UK keyboard with Mavericks.  Because Apple's idea of a UK keyboard is different to a non-apple UK keyboard, some symbols are wrong, e.g. " and @ are swapped.

How can I get set my keyboard layout to match a non-mac UK keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried the one provided by apple called "British PC"?

Comment: British PC doesn't alway work, \ and ` were swapped for me, this new layout fixed that.

Comment: What is the "this new layout" you are referring to?

Comment: Just using "British PC" layout worked for me, as per @kdt's email below. Look what I can type correctly now: @`\# :)

Answer (score 22):

If the British PC layout from apple is not right, some alternatives can be found at

http://liyang.hu/osx-british.xhtml

Comment: These can also go in ~/Library/Keyboard layouts if you don't want to pollute /Library. Also didn't need to logout/in doing this.

Comment: This also worked for me, with a Logitech K400 keyboard.  It's still a cheap/nasty keyboard, but at least the key mapping is correct...

Comment: for the lacking in observation (like me, it took me 10 mins to see),  you need to click on 'other' at the top to get access to these new maps.

Comment: Liyang's site is down rn but backups can be found here https://github.com/cbaggers/backup-uk-keyboard-layouts-for-macos

Answer (score 10):

After downloading alternatives from the link suggested in Tomg's answer, I realised while making them active that there is already a "British - PC" layout installed by default.

To activate it was Settings->Keyboard->Input Sources->Plus sign & find it from the list, and then click the input source icon in the menu bar to select it.

Comment: British PC doesn't alway get everything right, for example \ and ` swapped. This one does.

Comment: Do you really find that Apple's British PC does not put ` on the topmost leftmost key on an ISO keyboard as used in Europe?  What is "this one"?

Answer (score 5):

To get this working correctly (without downloading anything extra) I had to go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources.

British was the only option I had there, but clicking the + icon brought up a list which included British - PC. Simply add that one, THEN remove the original British option using the - icon.

My keyboard was correctly mapped to the British default after that. It didn't work until after I removed the original British option, so only British - PC was in Input Sources.

Comment: This was the right answer for me without having to add anything else. While I was adding `British - PC` to my layouts, it was never "picking it up". I was, however, able to add other layouts (Irish in particular) and switching between them worked afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answers. Alternatively there is a software called [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) with which you can remap your keyboard as you like. I didn't find this answer before when I was looking for the "proper" British-PC layout. With the app it takes 5-10 minutes to redo your keyboard - there are ready-made samples inside which you can use as a templates.

I hope it helps.